# How to see the +/- change in rolling average between two cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, cumulative-sum

[image: Bowling Scores]

As you can see from my picture, I have a list of bowling scores and some running averages. The issue I cannot seem to solve is I would like to be able to see the change in average between a game and the previous game. If the average goes down, it would say -1.2% for example or +2.1% if it goes up. I would really like negative averages to be in red and positive ones in green if that is possible.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DI5GFHgXK7wK4D6hwanllHFMSCPTRgQBLexwFXoRYEg/edit?usp=sharing) is a copy of my sheet with the desired output in column G.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired outtput

Comment: Added. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you will need running average:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(ISNUMBER(
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(SORT(REPT("♦ ", ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A2:A)))-1), 1, 0)&
 "♦"&TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, C2:C), "♦"), 999^99, COUNTA(A2:A))), 
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SPLIT(SORT(REPT("♦ ", ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A2:A)))-1), 1, 0)&
 "♦"&TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, C2:C), "♦"), 999^99, COUNTA(A2:A)), )),
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 "avg(Col"&ROW(A2:A)-ROW(A2)+1&")", ))&"")), 
 "select Col2", 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

then you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", {0; (INDIRECT("F2:F"&ROWS(F3:F))-F3:F)*-1}, ))
```

[image: 0]

---

and finally color format it:

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

with new functions, there is a new method...

`average = sum / count` therefore we can run running total / cumultative sum:

```
=SCAN(, A2:A20, LAMBDA(x, y, (x+y)))
```

[image]

and then just divide by sequence to get the running average:

```
=INDEX(SCAN(, A2:A20, LAMBDA(x, y, (x+y)))/(ROW(A2:A20)-1))
```

[image]

and to get the difference between `x` and `x+1` cells:

```
={0; MAP(B2:B19, LAMBDA(z, OFFSET(z, 1, )-z))}
```

[image]

and the final touch:

```
0[=0][black];    -0.00###[<0][red];    0.00####[color 50]
```

[image]

---

or in one go:

```
={0; INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN({QUERY(
 MAP(SCAN(, A2:A20, LAMBDA(x, y, (x+y))), ROW(A2:A20)-1, 
 LAMBDA(a, b, a/b)), "offset 1", ); ""}-
 MAP(SCAN(, A2:A20, LAMBDA(x, y, (x+y))), ROW(A2:A20)-1, 
 LAMBDA(a, b, a/b)), ROWS(A2:A20)-1, 1))}
```

[image]

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you. I wish I knew these formulas as well as C#.

Answer (score 1):

You get the change percentage using: `=ROUND((C3-C2)/C2*100,2)` in G3:G20.

Check:

- For going down from 145 to 123 this returns (with no rounding) -15.17241379.
- 145 + (145 * -15.17241379 / 100) = 123

For the colouring:

- Select the cells G3:G20.
- Go to -> Format -> Conditional formatting -> Format rules -> Format cells if… -> Greater than -> 0 -> Formatting style

  - -> [Down arrow next to letter A] -> [Pick your colour]
  - -> [Down arrow next to (bucket with) fill colour] -> [None]

PS: For the running average you can use: `=AVERAGE(C$2:C2)` in F2:F20.

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.